# Can a json response can be partially paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, pagination, json-api

I'm wondering if a json can be partially paginate.

For example

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever."
    }
  }],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "people",
      "id": 42,
      "attributes": {
        "name": "John"
      }
    },
    {
      ...annnd 80000 others
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `included` have soo many elements (80.000 for examples) than maybe we need pagination?
But if it's paginate and we go on the next page only `included` elements will change, the json will still return the data.articles.

Is it a correct behavior ?

First proposal :

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!",
        "body": "The shortest article. Ever."
      },
      "relationships": {
        "users": {
          "link": "https://website.com/api/v1/articles/1/users.json"
        }
      }
  }]
}
```

Comment: If the size of data.articles is going to be small, it is not going to really matter. If it is big enough, have a separate endpoint to paginate included articles

Comment: Would it be possible with your setup to replace `included` with [`links`](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-links), to add a `people` link specific to the data that you are requesting, and to then simply paginate those results? See also the [json pagination](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-pagination) documentation.

Comment: @emaillenin articles will be the only one element with may people.  @omnikron so `people` in a new get, nothing related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be compliant with the JSON API spec, your compound document must obey the [full linkage requirement](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents). Any included resources MUST be identified via relationship data.

In your example, you could fulfill this by adding a `data` member under the `users` relationship. You could then link to every included person.

If the relationship data is a partial set, you can use [pagination links within the relationship object](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships).